# Error running TestNG tests for apk file with different Android versions(8&9)

Tags: aws-device-farm

I am trying run a Appium script written in TestNG for a Android Mobile application in device farm.

When I run the test in device farm devices which are running lower version of Android like 6 and 7 run the tests successfully. However the devices runnning OS version 8 and 9 fail.

All the devices fail with the same error

It is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found or it is not accessible Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T14:04:26.12Z' System info: host: 'ip-172-31-13-65', ip: '172.31.13.65', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-139-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_151' Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver

I have attached screenshot as well.

Any help on this would be highly appreciated

[Device farm pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esDyb.png)

enter image description here1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yjDi.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPYT6.png)

Comment: Does it work locally with Android 8 and 9 as well? Might be a Device Farm issue or the tests.

Comment: Can you add your appium server logs here too?

Comment: I have added the logs as images hope this helps

Comment: I have even tried adding the desired capabilities to uiautomator2 but no luck still